# Angular 2 deployment using nginx

Tags: nginx, angular2-forms

Here below are the steps that I followed to deploy my Angular2 app locally using Nginx:

-Downloaded and unzip Nginx somewhere in my machine.

-Built my Angular app for production, using ng build command
ng build --prod

-Opened the ../nginx-1.13.8/conf/nginx.conf, and added the following script:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       9090;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /device-listing/ {
            proxy_pass https://apim.azure-api.net/devicelisting/device-listing; 
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

-Navigated to ../nginx-1.13.8/html, and copied inside it all the generated files from app/dist folder.

-Ran Nginx server by double click on ../nginx-1.13.8/nginx.exe.

-Opened the localhost:9090 with a browser and my Angular app is up and running.

**But when I click on Navigation link it gives me 405 Not Allowed error!!!!!
Basically its not redirecting to api call on the click of navigation link**

Network details:

[image]

Kindly suggest me what more configuration do i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mistakenly `POST`ing to an invalid URL, instead of your intended IP address.

Your post request goes to `http://localhost:9090/null`, did you intend for it to go to `http://localhost:9090/device-listing` instead?

---

If your API still does not work, this might be why:

`proxy_pass` will pass the entire path to the proxy. So when someone visits `/device-listing/` on your web server, their request will be passed to:

`https://apim.azure-api.net/devicelisting/device-listing/device-listing`

Note that `device-listing` is repeated twice.

If I had to guess, that's not a valid API method on your backend, so your API is returning 405 Not Allowed.

Changing your `proxy_pass` directive to `https://apim.azure-api.net/devicelisting/` should make it work like you expect.